# Task Scheduler runs without triggering action

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

I setup a task in Task Scheduler to run every 5 minutes with the history enabled.  The task triggers a batch file that does the following:

> ECHO Start Bat Program at %date% %time%>>log.txt
>
> START CustomProgramNoParameters.exe

I tested the batch file.  It works correctly(creates log entry then triggers program).
I tested manually running the task on Task Scheduler that that also works.
However, when the schedule runs, I've found the following.

> 1) Task Scheduler History says the task has started and completed.
>
> 2) Bat log file has had no new entries
>
> 3) My .exe program didn't trigger.

I've duplicated the settings/setup on several servers, I've found that this does not occur every time, but once it does occur on the server, I haven't found a way to fix it other than seek 3rd party alternatives.

Here are some details for the Task Schedule settings. Since this site doesn't like screenshots, let me know if there's any setting that I missed that could help clue in the cause of the issue. Below are settings for a job that runs every hour that has the exact same problems.

> General
>
> Run whether user is logged on or not.
>
> Run task under ComputerName\Administrator
>
> Configure for Windows Vista, Server 2008
>
> Schedule
>
> Begin task On a Schedule
>
> Daily - Start 10/26/2017 12:00 AM Recur Every 1 days
>
> Repeat Task every 1 hour for duration: 1 Day
>
> Stop task if it runs longer than 30 minutes
>
> Enabled
>
> Action
>
> Start .bat
>
> Conditions
>
> Start the task only if the power is on AC Power
>
> Stop if the computer switches to battery power
>
> Settings
>
> Allow task to be run on demand
>
> Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed
>
> Stop the task if it runs longer than 30 mintues
>
> If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop
>
> If the task is already running, then the following rule applies. Stop the existing instance

Comment: Near impossible to troubleshoot for you. We do not know the specific settings you used in task scheduler, nor do we know the exact contents of the batch file and its associated parameters.

Comment: I'll try to add the settings for windows task scheduler.  I don't think the bat file is really relevant I'll add that too to eliminate the variables

Comment: The last time someone said the bat file was relevant with the Task Scheduled task it actually was the bat file that was the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085250/how-to-schedule-a-daily-task-to-run-a-batch-file